# How do I replace paragraph breaks with line break in Word?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-365

How do I replace paragraph breaks (Enter key) with line breaks (shift+enter) in Word? I have copied a bunch of text from the .txt file opened in notepad. When I paste in Word each line of text seems to have become it's own paragraph. This takes up too much space on the Word page due to the spacing between paragraphs. Is there an easy way to search/replace paragraph breaks with line breaks?

Comment: you can also adjust the paragraph spacing

Comment: @jsotola I know I can. I want to replace paragraph breaks by line breaks instead

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
2. Find what: `^p`
3. Replace with: `^l`
4. Press <kbd>Replace All</kbd>

[image]

**Note:** The special characters (`^p`, `^l`, etc.) can be shown by pressing <kbd>Special</kbd>

- `^p` is Paragraph Mark
- `^l` is Manual Line Break

[image]